# What is the probability the statement is true given A and B contradict each other??(Slight twist in a very unique question)

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

The textbook question goes like this
A and B are independent witness in a case. The probability that A speaks the truth is 'x' and that of B is 'y'.If A and B agree on a certain statement, how to find the probability that the statement is true ?

the twist is-
Given A and B contradict on a certain statement
what is the the probabability that **The given statement is true**

I think the numerator should contain  --> a truth X b lie OR a lie x b truth
but i do not understand what will go in the denominator
I fancily think the whole answer is one, but without any clear reasoning.
Please help!

Comment: This is pretty vague.  If the two disagree then you know that one is lying and the other is telling the truth.  Not sure there's much more to be said without more detail (like which of them said what).

Comment: Insufficient information.  Is A the one that says that the statement is true, or is B the one that says that the statement is true?

Comment: Please give the exact wording of the problem, as it was assigned to you, or as you saw it on the internet.

Comment: I suspect that this could be one of those questions on here that could end up being, intentionally or unintentionally, quite interesting, even more so than the OP intended. There are some subtle things going on here. It is also possible that the book made a mistake and misworded what they were really looking for.

Comment: The following are all answerable from the given, in terms of $x$ and $y$ that is: A is asked a Y/N question and B is asked the same Y/N question. Then (I) what is the probability that A gets it right and B gets it right? (II) what is the probability that A gets it wrong and and B gets it wrong? (III) what is the probability that A gets it wrong and B gets it right? (IV) what is the probability that A gets it right and B gets it wrong.